# Using PowerShell To Count Sentences In A File

Tags: powershell, count, sentence

I am having an issue with my PowerShell Program counting the number of sentences in a file I am using. I am using the following code:

```
foreach ($Sentence in (Get-Content file))
{
    $i = $Sentence.Split("?")
    $n = $Sentence.Split(".")
    $Sentences += $i.Length
    $Sentences += $n.Length
}
```

The total number of sentences I should get is 61 but I am getting 71, could someone please help me out with this?  I have Sentences set to zero as well.

Thanks

Comment: We need to see your content file as well as your code.

Comment: If there are multiple sentences on the same line you can wind up double counting sentences by using split.  Why not just count the number of `?` and `.` characters?

Comment: @Vasili - you've changed the meaning of the OP's question by "fixing" it with your edit.  If s/he is doing a split on `?` and then on `.` then that's part of the question.

Comment: I changed it back a moment ago after realising this.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($Sentence in (Get-Content file))
{
    $i = $Sentence.Split("[?\.]")
    $Sentences = $i.Length
}
```

I edited your code a bit.

The `.` that you were using needs to be escaped, otherwise Powershell recognises it as a Regex `dotall` expression, which means "any character"

So you should split the string on `"[?\.]"` or similar.

Comment: By editing the question you have obscured the problem the OP is encountering. Just answer and show what you changed to make it correct; don't change the question.

Comment: This helped me out a little, I am not getting five more sentences in my count than I should.  I just do not see where it is getting the extra numbers from.

Comment: If you try this: `"test" -split "."`, you will see that it splits it over 4 lines, since `.` means "any character" in regex.

Comment: I am sorry I do not know how or where I can go to add the text file on the question @DiMono.

Answer (score 0):

When counting sentences, what you are looking for is where each sentence ends. Splitting, though, returns a collection of sentence fragments around those end characters, with the ends themselves represented by the gap between elements. Therefore, the number of sentences will equal the number of gaps, which is one less the number of fragments in the split result.

Of course, as [Keith Hill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153982/keith-hill) pointed out in a comment above, the actual splitting is unnecessary when you can count the ends directly.

```powershell
foreach( $Sentence in (Get-Content test.txt) ) {
  # Split at every occurrence of '.' and '?', and count the gaps.
  $Split = $Sentence.Split( '.?' )
  $SplitSentences += $Split.Count - 1

  # Count every occurrence of '.' and '?'.
  $Ends = [char[]]$Sentence -match '[.?]'
  $CountedSentences += $Ends.Count
}
```

---

Contents of `test.txt` file:

```
Is this a sentence? This is a 
sentence. Is this a sentence? 
This is a sentence. Is this a
very long sentence that spans
multiple lines?
```

Also, to clarify on the remarks to [Vasili's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21690156/2495): the PowerShell [`-split`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113270) operator interprets a string as a regular expression by default, while the .NET [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method only works with literal string values.

For example:

- `'Unclosed [bracket?' -split '[?]'` will treat `[?]` as a regular expression character class and match the `?` character, returning the two strings `'Unclosed [bracket'` and `''`
- `'Unclosed [bracket?'.Split( '[?]' )` will call the [`Split(char[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) overload and match each `[`, `?`, and `]` character, returning the three strings `'Unclosed '`, `'bracket'`, and `''`